# How to customize the GMSMarker View in IOS with google map SDK?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I want to implement a function in google map.

when tap(selected) the Marker then the Marker shown as a different color.

I think Marker is need to customized a View to show like a green circle when taped.
However `GMSMarker` has only a `@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImage icon`.
Anybody know how to implemet?

I Can't display the image (You need at least 10 reputation to post images.)

Comment: you could had posted a link if you really wanted to.

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921375/change-google-maps-selected-marker-or-change-markers-color-ios?answertab=oldest#tab-top. If not post the code for what you have so far.